# Using Facemark opencv contrib in android native C++

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I am new to opencv, I am trying to use Facemark in opencv contrib modules in my android native C++ app. However, i am getting the error

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x1788 in tid
>   21567(my_app)

when creating an instance of Facemark using

```
 Ptr<Facemark> facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();
```

I am using https://github.com/chaoyangnz/opencv3-android-sdk-with-contrib opencv library
here is my implementation
c++

```
    void
    Java_com_makeover_makeover_1opencv_MainActivity_nativeDetectFaceLandmarks(
            JNIEnv *env,
            jobject , jlong srcAddr, jlong retAddr,
            jstring faceCascadePath, jstring faceYamlPath)
    {
        const char *faceCascadeFile = env->GetStringUTFChars(faceCascadePath,NULL);
        const char *yamlFile = env->GetStringUTFChars(faceYamlPath,NULL);

        LOGI("nativeDetectFace called");
        string cascadePath(faceCascadeFile);

        LOGI("nativeDetectFace called");

        string yamlPath(yamlFile);

        Mat& colorMat = *(Mat*)srcAddr;
        Mat& retValMat = *(Mat*)retAddr;
        Mat gray;

        // Load Face Detector
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector(cascadePath);
        LOGI("cascade file loaded");

        // Create an instance of Facemark
        Ptr<Facemark> facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();

        LOGI("face instance created");


        // Load landmark detector
        facemark->loadModel(yamlPath);

        LOGI("yalm model loaded");

        // Find face
        vector<Rect> faces;
        // Convert frame to grayscale because
        // faceDetector requires grayscale image.
        cvtColor(colorMat, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // Detect faces
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);

        // Variable for landmarks.
        // Landmarks for one face is a vector of points
        // There can be more than one face in the image. Hence, we
        // use a vector of vector of points.
        vector< vector<Point2f> > landmarks;

        // Run landmark detector
        bool success = facemark->fit(colorMat,faces,landmarks);

        if(success)
        {
            // If successful, render the landmarks on the face
            for(int i = 0; i < landmarks.size(); i++)
            {
                drawLandmarks(colorMat, landmarks[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

java implementation

```
    drawFaces.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Mat colorMat,grayMat;
            colorMat = new Mat();
            grayMat = new Mat();

            Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp,colorMat);

            nativeDetectFaceLandmarks(colorMat.getNativeObjAddr(), grayMat.getNativeObjAddr(),
                    getCascade("face"),getCascade("yaml"));

            Bitmap new_bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp);
            Utils.matToBitmap(colorMat,new_bmp2);

            img_face.setImageBitmap(new_bmp2);

        }
    });
```

getCascade method

```
    public String getCascade(String cascadeType){
    String fileName;
    File mCascadeFile;
    final InputStream is;
    FileOutputStream os;
    switch (cascadeType){
        case "mouth":
            fileName="haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml";
            break;
        case "face":
            fileName = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
            break;
        case "right_eye":
            fileName = "haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml";
            break;

        case "yaml":
            fileName = "lbfmodel.yaml";
            break;


        case "left_eye":
            fileName = "haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml";
            break;
        default:
            fileName = null;
    }
    if(fileName==null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
        File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir,fileName);


        os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
        Log.i("TAG", "getCascade: face cascade found");
        return mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "face cascade not found", e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Anyone who knows what Iam doing wrong or a better way to use Facemark in opencv contrib modules in android native

Comment: What is the stacktrace after crash? https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug

Comment: [link](https://justpaste.it/7ar9i)  here is my stacktrace

Comment: From the stacktrace, the `SIGSEGV` happens in `je_free()`.  You're almost certainly corrupting your heap somewhere.  Are you checking the return value from **every single JNI call**?  How do you know the addresses held in `srcAddr` and `retAddr` are correct?

Comment: May not be related, but try passing your array size when reading from your input stream: `while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 4096)) != -1)` otherwise you could overflow the array

Answer (score 1):

Every tutorial I have seen so far has implemented this method in a different way, to clear this up I will go through the methods that work for me.

Firstly declaring facemark the below method returns the SIGSEGV error:

```
Ptr<Facemark> facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();
```

Instead use:

```
Ptr<Facemark> facemark = createFacemarkLBF();
```

Secondly I have seen many tutorials use:

```
facemark->load(filename);
```

But the correct syntax would be:

```
facemark->loadModel(filename);
```

If you still have the same issue follow this link and download link and get the latest SDK with contrib:

https://pullrequest.opencv.org/buildbot/export/opencv_releases/